# How to finish the activity in IntentService in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-intentservice

I am using GCMIntentService class extend IntentService to get the notification while click the notification i can launch the my activity. Its working but i can't finish my activity so i am facing the back button press problem.

*** Below code ***

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

In this code while launch the MainActivity and press the back button two times only it exist from app because i can't finish the activity in notification click. So please help me how to finish the activity in GCMIntentService class.

Comment: The first thing came in my mind, And I'm not saying it's the best solution, register for a Broadcast Receiver in your activity (A custom one that is acknowledged by your activity only), and from your service (And whenever want to close your activity) make a broadcast with this custom intent. And close your activity once it receives this intent.

Comment: Please give any idea and reference.

Comment: I'm going to add a code here as an answer, I'm getting it out of my project right now.

Comment: Make sure to check my answer again as I modified it to suit your request

Answer (score 1):

> So please help me how to finish the activity in GCMIntentService class.

That is not the right answer. What you want is to ensure that the task makes sense to the user, in terms of the back stack. Depending on your app's navigation, that could involve adding one of the following sets of flags to your `resultIntent`:

- `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` (if you want to keep other activities on the back stack, but ensure that there is only one instance of `MainActivity`)
- `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` *and* `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` (if you want to have a separate dedicated task for this `Notification` processing, leaving any existing task alone; this also requires `android:taskAffinity=""` in the `<activity>` element in the manifest)

Answer (score 0):

**In your activity creation or whenever you want, you will register your custom broadcast receiver:**

```
registerReceiver(closeMyActivity, new IntentFilter("ex.my_app_name.my_custom_broadcast"));
```

**This is where you will receive your custom broadcast to close your activity.**

```
private final BroadcastReceiver closeMyActivity = new BroadcastReceiver() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
                {
                    if (null != intent && intent.hasExtra("aCloseActivity")) {
                        if(intent.getBooleanExtra("aCloseActivity", false)){
                         // Here you can close your activity                                 
                         }
                     }
                }
            };
```

**Don't forget to unregister the broadcast receiver in your activity when it's destroyed:**

```
unregisterReceiver(closeMyActivity);
```

**And from your service send the broadcast:**

```
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("ex.my_app_name.my_custom_broadcast").putExtra("aCloseActivity", true));
```

I hope it helps, but also wait to see other replies, maybe there's a better solution.